# wget only saving first line of cookies

Tags: wget

I want to download and save all the cookies from a particular web-page when using wget. However, wget is only saving the first line. I want the saved cookies from wget to be the same as the cookies I am viewing from, say, Google Chrome Developer tools.

The line I am using is:

```
wget "<website here>" --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookies.txt
```

Then, when I check cookies.txt, it is not the same as if I loaded "[website]" in Google Chrome and viewed the cookies in the Developer Tools window.

How do I download and save all the cookies in wget?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wget only "sees" the cookies set by the server. It doesn't process JavaScript code, so you don't get e.g. Google Analytics cookies.

Example www.t3n.de:
[image: t3n Cookies Chrome]

But with wget this looks like this (no cookies found):

```
$ wget www.t3n.de -q --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookies.txt -O /dev/null && cat cookies.txt
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2014-06-19 13:53:30.
# Edit at your own risk.
```